# Redis PSUBSCRIBE Problems

Tags: redis, redis-py

A server is sending a message via Redis on a channel composed of some name and a unique id. I need to essentially find this channel and publish something back to it.

So far, I tried reading the documentation and experimenting with PSUBSCRIBE. However, the message that is received doesn't have the full channel name. It just has the pattern that I sent to PSUBSCRIBE. So, how can I go about finding the channel name?

I also included some code below if that would help understand my logic.

```
    red = redis.StrictRedis(...)
    pub = red.pubsub()
    pub.psubscribe("name_pattern*")

    for msg in pub.listen():
        if msg["data"] == "...":
            channel_name = msg["channel"]

    red.publish(channel_name, "SOME MESSAGE")
```

Comment: Shouldn't `redis_consumer.publish(channel_name, "SOME MESSAGE")` reside inside the `if` block?

Comment: Inside the if block I could do: `red.publish(msg["channel"], "SOME_MESSAGE")`. I'm concerned this still won't publish because the true channel name isn't being passed only the pattern.

Comment: The channel looks to be returned currently from my experimentations - please include more details.